# Multiple dex files error while building an apk in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

[GRADLE FILE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PNPd.png)
.........and.............
[LOG IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azqlp.png)

I am getting the following error while building apk file in `Android Studio`:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzb;
```

Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: post your gradle file portion where you have defined libraries

Comment: I added as image....please go through it

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
     defaultConfig {
    ...
            minSdkVersion 
            targetSdkVersion 
            multiDexEnabled true <-- the line that matters
          }
...
}
```

Comment: what is actually problem.plz upload full log

Comment: I added image to my question. please see it and help me

Comment: you can try this :~ dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }